# Is config.sys_language_mode in TYPO3 9 with existing site configuration working any more?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

in a site with a site definition for a foreign language

```
fallbackType: fallback
```

i need for one page branch a different bahavior. Up to TYPO3 8 i used an extension template with

config.sys_language_mode = strict

which did the job. But in TYPO3 9 with an existing site definition this entry seems not to work anymore. Accordiong to the manual

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-frontendlocalization/master/en-us/LocalizationModes/Index.html

it should work but it does not.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/UseSiteInConditions.html is that conditioning helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not helpful. I do not want to _use_ the site configuration in a condition but to _set_ the site configuration with the help of a condition or with typoscript. The other way round ...

Comment: I see, will look into it later a bit more! Hope you figure it out sooner maybe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility is a custom middleware handler. Look here for more details: [Change language parameters in site configuration for some pages in a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007240/change-language-parameters-in-site-configuration-for-some-pages-in-a-site)