# TYPO3 9.5: use content-fallback mode for single pages / override site-configuration

Tags: typo3, typoscript

is it possible to define content-fallback mode for a single page f.e.g via an extension-template and typoscript or is the language-mode definitifly a site-wide configuration that can not be overriden via typoscript ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I asked nearly the same question a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062802/is-config-sys-language-mode-in-typo3-9-with-existing-site-configuration-working - it seems there is no solution. Perhaps we should announce this as bug.